# MagicalRecord unit testing and creating entities

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to create a unit test for Core Data.

This is my setup method:

```
- (void)setUp {
        [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];
        [MagicalRecord setDefaultModelFromClass:[Person class]];
        _context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
        _adapter = [[CoreDataAdapter alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:_context];
    }
```

The method I want to test:

```
- (Person *)adaptToPerson:(NSDictionary *)person {
    return [Person MR_createInContext:_context];
}
```

The Person is a subclass of NSManagedObjectContext like it should be.

But when I run my unit test that calls the adaptToPerson method it doesn't run.
I get the following output

> -[CoreDataAdapterTest testAdaptToPerson] : +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Person' in this model.

How can I make sure that the Person class in known to the managedObjectContext set up by magicalRecord.

Comment: Your setup is backwards. Move the setdefaultmanagedobjectmodel call before the stack setup. Your stack is not using the model you're expecting

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem...

Comment: Also make sure your test model is included in your test bundle